# Sorting Arrays of Object by double and have a specific String value

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So, I have this piece of code for sorting arrays of object :

```
bensin[] banding=new bensin[7];
for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    banding[i] = new bensin(output[i].getJenis(),
                            output[i].getKetTotal(),
                            output[i].getHarga(),
                            output[i].getKapTotal(),
                            output[i].getMax());
}

@Override
public int compareTo(bensin o) {
    if (this.harga < o.harga) {
        return -1;
    } else if (this.harga == o.harga) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And in the main class :

```
Arrays.sort(banding);
for (bensin o : banding) {
    jTextField.setText(Double.toString(o.getHarga()));
}
```

And the result only a the highest number from the sort.
But I need is highest Double value that have String value that specific like :

```
banding.getJenis().equals("example")
```

Please help, I really need this. Thank you

PS.
Maybe i'm not clear enough. So what i mean is i'm looking for the highest value but that value doesn't higher that a limit that user set. So the String i meant is the comparison between limit and total calculated value. String have to value "ENOUGH" and "OVERFLOWING"

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names are written in PascalCase and therefore start with uppercase.

Comment: Off topic: rather than looping over your sorted array and assigning the same text field a value multiple times just access the last value directly and assign that single value (or the first value if you reverse the sort)

Comment: @MCEmperor thanks for the tips will follow that in the future

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yeah i tried that, but it only have value 0.0 when i access it ,i really wonder why

Comment: Either way you will only have the last value of your array in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the data before or after you sort it.

```
List<bensin> examples = Arrays.stream(banding)
    .filter(o -> o.getJenis().equals("example"))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(bensin::getHarga))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Where do i put that code? And Is there any changes from the original code? Because i still get the highest value and doesn't have that specific String value

Comment: @judasnitch you replace your current sorting with it.